How does Lazy loading works with useTransition Hook?
import { lazy, Suspense, useState, useTransition } from "react";
const AdminData = lazy(() => import("./AdminData"));

export default function Home() {
  const [isAdmin, setAdmin] = useState(false);
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          import("../sum").then((module) => {
            alert(module.default(2, 2));
          });
        }}
      >
        Add 2+2
      </button>

      <br />
      <br />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          startTransition(() => {
            setAdmin(!isAdmin);
          });
        }}
      >
        Toggle Admin
      </button>
      {isPending && "Loading...."}
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>
        {isAdmin ? <AdminData /> : <h2>You are not an Admin</h2>}
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}

My assumption is that AdminData should be lazily loaded only when isAdmin is set to true, assuming the last render was our initial render.
If I make setAdmin(!isAdmin) a low-priority update, and there are no other tasks or updates in the queue, pressing the "Toggle Admin" button should immediately update isAdmin to true. This state change should trigger a re-render of the component.
Since the transition was complete right away, isPending should be false, meaning the expression {isPending && "Loading..."} should evaluate to false (and not display "Loading..."). Instead, we should get the fallback from Suspense i.e <h1>Loading...</h1>.
However, when I press the "Toggle Admin" button, it seems that AdminData is loaded first, and then setAdmin is invoked. Am I missing something here? Can someone explain exactly what’s happening?

I think, the key point is that the transition (isPending) and the lazy loading (Suspense) are both asynchronous processes. The isPending state might not immediately reflect the loading state of AdminData because React batches updates and handles them asynchronously.

I don't think them being async matters much here. Here's the explanation I got on reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/1ge4nwl/how_does_lazy_loading_works_with_usetransition/
